# Windows couldn't start the service on Local Computer

Tags: java, windows-services

I've been created an windows service with WinRun4J. The application is successfully installed as service. But when I try to start the service with run `net start service` in command prompt , the service wouldn't start. Then I try to start the service via windows: Services -> Start the service, the popup message has come up "Windows couldn't start the service on Local Computer". Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved my problem. 
I'm using `winsw` to run my java application as windows service.

More : http://github.com/kohsuke/winsw